# read() from file return what?

Tags: c, linux, io, blocking

in all reference below:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/

https://linux.die.net/man/3/read

it says:

> When attempting to read a file (other than a pipe or FIFO) that
>   supports non-blocking reads and has no data currently available:
>
> If O_NONBLOCK is set, read() shall return -1 and set errno to
>   [EAGAIN].
>
> If O_NONBLOCK is clear, read() shall block the calling thread until
>   some data becomes available.
>
> The use of the O_NONBLOCK flag has no effect if there is some data
>   available.

But who really try it? As I tested, all above cases would let read() return 0.

It seems O_NONBLOCK is not working no matter I set it this way:

```
int flags = O_RDONLY;
int mode = S_IRGRP|S_IROTH|S_IRUSR;
int _pbfd = (::open)("123",flags,mode);
```

Or this way:

```
int _pbfd = (::open)("123",flags,mode);
int saved_flags = fcntl(_pbfd, F_GETFL);
fcntl(_pbfd, F_SETFL, saved_flags & ~O_NONBLOCK);
```

Comment: `(::open)` looks more like C++ with unnecessary parentheses than C.

Comment: It doesn't look like any of those sets `O_NONBLOCK` to me. The second explicitly clears it.

Comment: Non-blocking IO is used pretty widely, and has been for a long time.  Instead of supposing that it doesn't work as documented, you should probably conclude that you're not using it (correctly).

Comment: This site http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html says: "O_NONBLOCK or O_NDELAY: ..... Note that this flag has **no effect for regular files**  ...."

Comment: Among other things, regardless of non-blocking mode, `read()` will return 0 if that's how many bytes you request, or if the current file offset is at or past the end of the file.

Comment: @molbdnilo, yes, both way just clear O_NONBLOCK, as I want block behavior, but it is not working

Comment: @JohnBollinger tell me what is the correctly use? Have you tried it? "return 0 if  at or past the end of the file" is also from the document, doesn't it conflict with  "shall return -1" or "shall block the calling thread"

Comment: @4386427 got it, very helpful. So maybe "file that supports non-blocking reads" is not regular file.

Answer (score 1):

The key part of [the POSIX `read()` specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html) that applies is bolded:

> When attempting to read a file (other than a pipe or FIFO) **that
>   supports non-blocking reads** and has no data currently available:
>
> - If `O_NONBLOCK` is set, `read()` shall return `-1` and set `errno` to `[EAGAIN]`.
> - If `O_NONBLOCK` is clear, `read()` shall block the calling thread until some data becomes available.
> - The use of the `O_NONBLOCK` flag has no effect if there is some data available.

The underlying file system has to be designed and written to support non-blocking reads, and most file systems do not do that for files.

It's impossible to know why filesystem developers have not written many filesystems that support `O_NONBLOCK` (if any...), but it's likely because it's not useful for a file.  File objects have a *state* - the filesystem knows if there's data available or not, and there is no outside dependency were some data might suddenly appear in a way that won't effect the state of the file.

While, "You've read the whole file" is different from, "There's nothing in the pipe (yet)", there's not so much difference in the information returned to the caller.

Comment: Ok, i think you are right, a lot of file system like mine did not implement "supports non-blocking" for file. So that's why read() always return 0 if it read to the tip of file.

Comment: @guangchen The POSIX standard does seem to have the wording backwards - `read()` on a normal file is normally non-blocking.  What I think the standard is trying to say is "non-blocking reads **as a special case**", meaning that setting `O_NONBLOCK` is treated differently.  As noted in the comments above, Linux explicitly states that the flag has no effect on regular files.